# CSS Child selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with another table embedded in it like:

```css
table.index {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #61a2d1;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table.index > thead > tr:first-child {
  background-color: #61a2d1;
}
table.index > thead > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
table.index > thead > tr:first-child > td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
table.index > thead td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
table.index > tr:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(97, 162, 209, 0.5);
}
table.index > tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffda6d;
}
table.index > tbody > tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
table.index > tbody > tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
table.index .no-right-borrder {
  border-right: none;
}
table.index .no-left-border {
  border-left: none;
  text-align: right;
}
table.details {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px #61a2d1;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
 <table class="index" style="width:100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td style="width:2%"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="no-right-borrder" style="vertical-align:middle"><span class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></span></td>
   <td class="no-left-border" style="text-align:left;"></td>
   <td class="no-right-borrder" style="text-align:center"></td>
   <td class="no-left-border"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="4" style="padding:0;margin:0">
   <table class="details" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for=""></label></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for=""></label></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for=""></label></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for=""></label></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

When I open this page, the cells in the table with the class `details` have rounded corners just like the cells in the table with the class `index`.

I've used the direct child selector to indicate that I only wanted the routed borders to be applied to direct children of a table with the `index` class, so I'm not sure why it's happening.  When I examine the DOM in Google Developer Tools, it tells me that the `border-radius` attribute is coming from the `.index` class.  What do I need to do to stop that from happening?

edit:  This is what I'm seeing on my local machine.  CSS code is copied exactly from my code.  Table was simplified because it's auto-generated, but the classes are applied identically.

[image]

Comment: The inner (details) table looks squared off to me.

Comment: Thats right.. it's squared. Not  rounded.

Comment: OK.  I had no idea that it was going to create a code snippet out of my code.  However, when running it on my local machine, that is not the result I'm getting.

Comment: @DrewB: j08691 edited your question. Its not auto-generated code snippet.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the system created the snippet or I did (it was me BTW), the point is that the code you posted to your question doesn't have the problem you described. So you need to either add the code your example is missing, or look deeper into what may be the cause.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to place blame, just express surprise that a code snippet was there because I hadn't looked to see that you had edited it.  The CSS I'm working with is identical to what is posted.  For all intents and purposes, the HTML is identical as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to change `table.index > tbody > tr:last-child td:first-child` into `table.index > tbody > tr:last-child > td:first-child` (putting the direct descendant selector between `tr > td`), and the same for the `td:last-child` selector that directly follows.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something simple that I was looking over, but I'd been looking at it too long and needed a different perspective.  Kinda sux being the only developer in the office.

Comment: No problem! P.S. It may be worth looking into code pre-processors like SCSS - after a small learning curve and a little time for implementation, they end up cutting the amount of code down you write by a lot, making syntax errors like this much easier to spot.

Comment: I'm actually using SCSS already.  I just didn't know if it would be "proper" to post it rather than the generated CSS.

Comment: Fair enough, not sure what the standard here is either, and looks like not supported by stackoverflow code snippets, in anycase.